Simple button that grows on tap has a strange un-necessary animation
I am trying to create a view that has buttons that grow individually when you tap them.
For whatever reason I am getting an animation that suggests that the IDs are not stable and the animation system is re creating these elements.
You see them disappear and have a weird sizing animation rather than smoothly growing.
This also creates issues for a modifier I added to the inner stack with an onGeometryChange(Size) making it detect changes that didn’t actually happen.
struct GrowingButton: View {
    var axis: Axis.Set = .vertical
    @State private var size: CGFloat = 1

    var width: CGFloat {
        axis.contains(.horizontal) ? 50.0 + 50.0 * size : 100
    }

    var height: CGFloat {
        axis.contains(.vertical) ? 50.0 + 50.0 * size : 100
    }
    var body: some View {
        Button { size += 1 } label: {
            Text("\(size)")
                .padding()
                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                .background{Color.gray}
        }
    }
}

struct TestView: View {

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            HStack {
                GrowingButton(axis: .horizontal)
                GrowingButton(axis: .horizontal)
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 230, height: 100)
    }
}

I have tried giving each GrowingButton instance a .id argument with an int but that is not helping.

Have you tried scaling the button, instead of increasing its frame size?

The "disappearing" you mention is part of the default button animation. Button comes with its own set of animation. If you do not want this use a different UI building block. A simple rectangle with an onTapGesture should do the job.

That was it for the animation. So looks like the onGeometryChange is unrelated. Voting to close, opening a new question focused on the onGeometryChange

You don't need to vote to close your own question; You can either delete it or add an answer if you think the question is valuable for others
